# Building a stock screener : a web app similar to FinViz.com

Tags: mysql, node.js, stocks, nosql

I want to build my own stock screener for a specific exchange (that trades only stocks), but I am wondering what technologies would best fit my project ?

My requirements are :

- a friendly user-interface (maps, graphs, vizualisations, etc)
- a very fast response (eveything should load / compile results and return
  output to the enduser fast)
- database choice : I will have historical data and real-time data : should I use both RDBMS and NoSQL databases ?

**Issue :** The exchange doesn't provide any API, so I will need to scrape the real-time data published in its website. Do you think that this will cause performance issues ? Any suggestions ?